# How to show the hidden row below as long as I fill data in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to fill information in two different zones of a sheet.

The first zone to enter user data is from 2 to 100, where I only show the first row to be filled (row 2). When the user enters data in no matter what column, row 3 has to show. Then, when the user enters data in the 3rd row, row 4 has to show, and so on.

The second area is from 101 to the end of the sheet. So I need to do this to make visible row 101 when the user opens the sheet if there is no data from row 3 to row 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make rows hidden use this:

```
(this has to be in ThisWorkbook)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(2).Hidden = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Rows(2), Rows(1000)).Hidden = True 'Range Hidden
```

this makro will check if data is in Col 1 and will show row 1-100 if theres no data in row 3- 100 and will be executed when the workbook is opened:

```
(this has to be in ThisWorkbook)
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim lastRow
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If lastRow < 3 and lastRow <101 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Rows(3), Rows(100)).Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Rows(101), Rows(1000)).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

You can use a function that will be called whenever something from line 1 to 100 is changed to make the next Row visible like this:

```
(this has to be in the sheet that u want to watch i.e Sheet1 for me)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RowChanged as Integer
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range(Rows(1), Rows(100))

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

       RowChanged = Target.Row 'Row that changed
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(RowChanged + 1).Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, the last example is the one I was looking for.

There is only the definition of RowChanged as Integer missing, and it works like a charm.

Thank you @ugp!